# Microsoft Excel - How do I make every letter I type have a value so I can SUM the letters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm working on setting up my spreadsheet so that I can type in a letter that has a value no matter where I type the letter.

I have added value to all of these letters listed, but I don't know how to make it so the value is added to a new letter I type in.

[image: I have added value to all of these letters listed, but I don't know how to make it so the value is added to a new letter I type in.]

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Have you considered using VLOOKUP?  You would sum the lookup values.  BTW, your example doesn't reflect the problem description or the displayed formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables in excel very easily.

**First, type out your list of variables in one column.** For example, lets say you want to declare x, y and z. Type x into A1, y into A2, and z into A3.

**Second, input the corresponding values for each variable into the adjacent column.** For example, lets say you want to declare x=3, y=-2, z=0. Input 3 into B1, -2 into B2, and 0 into B3.

**Third, select all the cells containing your variables and constants** (A1 through B3 in our example). **Go to FORMULAS and "Create from Selection". Select "Left Column" and press OK.** Now all your variables are mapped to their respective values.

You can perform any operation anywhere else on your spreadsheet now using the variables. For instance if you want to sum them all, simply type `=SUM(x,y,z)` into any cell.

Comment: Very nice, Skylar. Ahkil, just to state the obvious, if you follow this procedure and define all your letters as variables, then wherever you type them, they will have the defined value.  And you can sum them or apply other calculations.